# Mapper does not contain definition for CreateMap C#

Tags: javascript, c#, linq, mapper, automapper-3

```
public IEnumerable<NotificationDto> GetNewNotifications()
{
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var notifications = _context.UserNotifications
         .Where(un => un.UserId == userId)
         .Select(un => un.Notification)
         .Include(n => n.Gig.Artist)
         .ToList();

    Mapper.CreateMap<ApplicationUser, UserDto>();
    Mapper.CreateMap<Gig, GigDto>();
    Mapper.CreateMap<Notification, NotificationDto>();

    return notifications.Select(Mapper.Map<Notification, NotificationDto>);
}
```

Can you please help me to define properly this **CreateMap** and explain why this message is displayed after defining it this way? Why it cannot find this **method**?

Comment: Please see the upgrade details of AutoMapper https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/5.0-Upgrade-Guide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Ben has noted, using the static Mapper to create maps is deprecated in version 5. In any case, the code example you have show would have bad performance, because you would have reconfigured the maps on every request.

Instead, put the mapping configuration into a `AutoMapper.Profile` and initialize the mapper **only once** on application startup.

```
using AutoMapper;

// reuse configurations by putting them into a profile
public class MyMappingProfile : Profile {
    public MyMappingProfile() {
        CreateMap<ApplicationUser, UserDto>();
        CreateMap<Gig, GigDto>();
        CreateMap<Notification, NotificationDto>();
    }
}

// initialize Mapper only once on application/service start!
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
    cfg.AddProfile<MyMappingProfile>();
});
```

[AutoMapper Configuration](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration)

Comment: Ah sorry, it should be `CreateMap<Gig, GigDto>();` instead of `Mapper.CreateMap<Gig, GigDto>();` in the profile. I edited the answer